# Getting 400 Bad Request after using date function field in jsp/controller

Tags: date, spring-mvc

I am getting HTTP 400 bad request error when i tried to use date in my application. It was works fine without date but with date it gives 400 error. Is there any way i can get rid of this error.

**Controller class**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createfeedback", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String postcreatefeedback(@ModelAttribute("feedback") Feedback feedback,  Locale locale, HttpServletRequest req, Map<String, Object> map) {
    logger.info("Welcome to Create Feedback page ! POST Method : The client locale is {}.", locale);
    Feedback check = feedbackService.getFeedback(feedback.getName());

    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    if (check == null) {
        feedback.setUser(userService.userExists(email.substring(2)));
        feedback.setCreated();
        feedbackService.addFeedback(feedback);
        logger.debug("Feedback Created");
        return "redirect:feedbackmanager.html";
    } else {
        logger.error("Feedback name already exists");
        return "redirect:createfeedback.html";
    }
}
```

**Feedback Class**

```
@Entity @Table(name="feedback")
public class Feedback {

    @Id @Column @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="feedback_name")
    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")
    @Column(name = "created")
    private Date created;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")
    @Column(name = "date_from")
    private Date date_from;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm")
    @Column(name = "date_to")
    private Date date_to;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="subject_id")
    private Subject subject;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="question_set_id")
    private Question_Set question_set;

    //Setter and Getter
}
```

**JSP Page**

```
<tiles:insertDefinition name="adminTemplate">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css"/>

        <script src="http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <div class="col-sm-9">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><spring:message code="app.panel.title.createfeedback" /></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form:form commandName="feedback">
                        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="name"><spring:message code="app.form.name" /></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <form:input cssClass="form-control" path="name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="question_set"><spring:message
                                                code="app.panel.questionset" /></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <form:select class="form-control" path="question_set.id">
                                                    <c:forEach items="${questionsetList}" var="questionset">
                                                        <option value="${questionset.id}">${questionset.name}</option>
                                                    </c:forEach>
                                                </form:select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <a href="questionsetmanager.html"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-sm-12"> <spring:message
                                                        code="app.panel.questionset" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="date_from"><spring:message code="app.panel.datefrom" /></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-group date">
                                            <form:input path="date_from" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                            <span class="add-on input-group-addon"> 
                                                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> </i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(function() {
                                            $('#datetimepicker1')
                                                    .datetimepicker({
                                                        language : 'en',
                                                        pick12HourFormat : true
                                                    });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="date_to"><spring:message code="app.panel.dateto" /></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-group date">
                                            <form:input path="date_to" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy" type="text" class="form-control" />
                                            <span class="add-on input-group-addon"> 
                                                <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> </i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(function() {
                                            $('#datetimepicker2')
                                                    .datetimepicker({
                                                        language : 'en',
                                                        pick12HourFormat : true
                                                    });
                                        });
                                    </script>
                                </div>
                                <br>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <label for="subject"><spring:message
                                                code="app.panel.subject" /></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                                <form:select class="form-control" path="subject.id">
                                                    <c:forEach items="${subjectList}" var="subject">
                                                        <option value="${subject.id}">${subject.name}</option>
                                                    </c:forEach>
                                                </form:select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                <a href="subjectmanager.html"
                                                    class="btn btn-sm btn-primary col-sm-12"><spring:message
                                                        code="app.panel.subject" /></a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br> <br />
                                <br />
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="${loggedInUserEMAIL}"/>
                                        <button type="submit"
                                            class="btn btn-sm btn-success form-control">
                                            <spring:message code="app.btn.save" />
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form:form>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

Comment: By the way, you should really use Java naming conventions for your attributes (Camel Case) : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Thank you Michael. I go through it. I will certainly  improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you register some kind of editor for `java.util.Date` ?

This can be done in a bean implementing `org.springframework.web.bind.support.WebBindingInitializer` :

```
/**
 * Initialize web bindings
 */
public class MyAppBindingInitializer implements WebBindingInitializer {

    /**
     * Date pattern applied to all the web app dates
     */
    public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, WebRequest request) {
        // Date editor with pattern
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_PATTERN);
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));

        // Trim Strings
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
        // Number editors
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Integer.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Integer.class, true));
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Long.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Long.class, true));

        // Custom types
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Profile.class, new ProfileEditor());
        binder.registerCustomEditor(OrderType.class, new OrderTypeEditor());
    }

}
```

And in your Spring configuration, if you are using XML :

```
   <!-- Binder used to convert strings to other types in the web tier -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="webBindingInitializer">
            <bean class="my.app.MyAppBindingInitializer "/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Yes i have register it with java.util.Date;. I didn't include import section of my program. I will try this solution and let you know if i get any error. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: can you include how you registered the date editor ? you may have a format difference between what you declared in your JSP and configuration

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you guys to help me. I just added 'BindingResult result' to my function and now things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logs. 
Maybe you need to include JodaTime jar into your project, and then you can use DateTimeFormat without MyAppBindingInitializer